# redirect old links (HTML site) to a new page (PHP site)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Recently I built a site with php but the old site they had was all in HTML. So now I dont know what what is the best way to redirect all those old links to the new site (maybe redirect all links with HTML to the main domain) with .htaccess, what is the best practice ?

Here is what I have tried but the site says to many redirect loops:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch "\.html$" http://www.example.de
```

So first we redirect all non-www links to www, then when the page has .html in the end to redirect to the main site.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question correctly - but maybe using URL rewrite - then you can link all .html to the new .php files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Redirect all old `.html`link to new sites's /**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.html$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

**Option 2: If `.html` file name and `.php` file names are same then redirect all old `.html`link to new sites's `.php` /**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1.php [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if it is a new domain you need to point to, add a domain pointer from the old domain to point towards the new domain, this will resolve in the server handling the redirect, this is the most efficient way.

This will work better than .htaccess because it's faster and does not cause a second initial page load (due to redirect).

If you don't have access to the server or domainpointers you could make the index.html an index.php file if php runs on the old server, from here simply put:

```
header('Location: http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

This will automatically redirect.

Hope this helped you.

‐ Sid

Comment: its on the same server, but the old site had all the pages in html, so I cant put php tags on them.

Comment: Why don't you put the new PHP website in the directory the current website is in? Saves a redirect.

Comment: yes it is in the same directory but the old links are all in .html and the new links are in .php (different from the old structure) so now when I am going to delete those old html files users and search engines will get 404 error

Comment: What you would do is first- replace all the .html links with .php links. After that you would test if everything was operational. If that is the case, delete the old HTML website and implement the new one.